# Multiply numbers using fork and a pipe

Tags: c, multiprocessing, pipe, fork

For this assignment, we are required to multiply two numbers on multiple processes. The first number gets multiplied by each digit from the second number, multiplied by its position (1, 10th, 100th, etc) and then sum all those numbers.
Supposedly the sum will be collected via the parent's pipe which is shared by all child processes but for some reason my code freezes when I run it. Also if I don't use the pipe and use the commented line, it works fine which doesn't make sense since the child processes shouldn't be able to access the parent variable `multiplicationResult`.

````
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

int digits (int n) {
    if (n < 0) n = (n == INT_MIN) ? INT_MAX : -n;
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    if (n < 100) return 2;
    if (n < 1000) return 3;
    if (n < 10000) return 4;
    if (n < 100000) return 5;
    if (n < 1000000) return 6;
    if (n < 10000000) return 7;
    if (n < 100000000) return 8;
    if (n < 1000000000) return 9;
    return 10;
}

int main() {
  int firstNumber = 23;
  int secondNumber = 233435;
  int secondNumberDigitsCount = digits(secondNumber);
  int parentPipe[2];

  printf("Second number's digits count = %d\n", secondNumberDigitsCount);

  pipe(parentPipe);

  int secondNumberDigitsArray[secondNumberDigitsCount];
  for (int i=0; i<secondNumberDigitsCount; i++) {
    secondNumberDigitsArray[i] = secondNumber % 10;
    secondNumber /= 10;
  }

  int multiplicationResult = 0;

  int digitPositionMultiplier = 1;
  for (int i=1; i<secondNumberDigitsCount+1; i++) {
    int secondNumberDigit = secondNumberDigitsArray[i-1];

    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child > 0) {
    printf("Child %d created\n", child);
    int digitByMultiplierByFirstNumber = digitPositionMultiplier * secondNumberDigit * firstNumber;
    printf("Digit by mulitplier %d\n", digitByMultiplierByFirstNumber);
    digitPositionMultiplier = digitPositionMultiplier * 10;
    // multiplicationResult += digitByMultiplierByFirstNumber;
    int currentMultiplicationResult;
    read(parentPipe[0], &currentMultiplicationResult, sizeof(currentMultiplicationResult));
    currentMultiplicationResult += digitByMultiplierByFirstNumber;
      return 0;
      return 0;
    write(parentPipe[1], &currentMultiplicationResult, sizeof(multiplicationResult));
    }
    else if (child == 0) {
      printf("Child terminating\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }

  while (wait(NULL) > 0);

  printf("Multiplication result %d\n", multiplicationResult);
  printf("Parent terminating\n");
  return 0;
}
```multiplicationResult
````

Comment: `else if (child == 0) return 0;` That's very odd code. That code path is the child process. Why are you using `fork` to create the child and then immediately exiting? The code you have in `if (child > 0)` is the parent process not the child. So there is no point forking if you just then do everything in the parent process.

Comment: "the child processes shouldn't be able to access the parent variable" That's explained by my previous comment. All the processing is being done in the parent and not the children.

Comment: [man fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html): "On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0  is returned in the child"

Comment: Fun little problem!  https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/master/c/fork-multiply.c

Comment: I am not sure how the main function works there. @WilliamPursell

Comment: @Tarek you'll need to be a little more specific if you want an explanation of something.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am not sure how run your code. I am not accustomed to a main function with parameters.

Comment: Are you running in a shell?  Just pass command line arguments.  e.g. ./a.out 5 10

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell